# proving $ \int_{\Omega} (b \cdot\nabla u)\,v=-\int_{\Omega} (b \cdot \nabla v )\,u\,+\,\int_{\partial \Omega} v\,(n\cdot bu) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, finite-element-method

Assume $b$ is a constant vector, $v \in V_h$ where $V_h$ is a space of functions and $\Omega$ is our domain of integration.

$$
\int_{\Omega} (b \cdot\nabla u)\,v=-\int_{\Omega} (b \cdot \nabla v )\,u\,+\,\int_{\partial \Omega} v\,(n\cdot bu)
$$

How is Green's formula applied in the above integral?

Comment: $\nabla\cdot(buv)=b\cdot\nabla(uv)=(b\cdot\nabla u)v+(b\cdot\nabla v)u$ and apply divergence theorem.